# Codeigniter -> counting table numbers and show on the page

Tags: codeigniter

I wanna show number of rows of table on my website.
query is working on mysql page. it shows 1292.

Model

```
function count_bookmark()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_BOOKMARK_HISTORY';
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        if($result->num_rows() <= 0)
            return FALSE;
        else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
$data['count'] = $this->admin_model->count_bookmark();
```

View

```
<?=$count?>
```

This only show number 1.

Comment: you are basically correct but you need to return the num_rows() instead of true

Comment: @Henesnarfel: I don't think that's correct. `num_rows()` returns the number of records from the resulting query which, when doing `COUNT,  will only be 1 record. It does not return the actual number of rows in the table.

Comment: @Colin Crap, you're right. totally missed that.  He needs to at least remove the `COUNT()` or use your method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're simply returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` from your model. `$count` is then evaluated as `1`. You need to return the actual count rather than just a boolean.

Also, to simplify things, you can use CodeIgniter's handy `count_all` method:

```
$count = $this->db->count_all('T_BOOKMARK_HISTORY');

return $count;
```

Then, in your view:

```
<?= $count ?>
```

Comment: @jakedyson: Great! I'm glad it's working for you. Please consider marking the answer as "accepted" if it solved your solution. [You can read more about that here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).